# Forcing ios number pad on contenteditable div

Tags: html, ios, knockout.js

```
<div contenteditable="true">0</div>
```

I have an application written with the Knockout library in which, instead of using  elements to collect information from a user, the original dev used `<div>`s which are set as `contenteditable`. While the application works, the only type of data that it collects is numeric so I'd like to prompt ios and android devices to open their number pads rather than their general keyboards when a user clicks on a field. Normally this is something that is done by setting in `input` type to 'tel' or 'numeric' but they don't seem to work for non inputs.

Is there an alternate way to do this?